# Difference between URL and URLConnection?

Tags: java, url, urlconnection

What is the difference between URL and URLConnection,  Can provide some examples or refer to me??

Comment: Well, one is an [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and the other is an [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)

Comment: Basically, the same difference there is between a phone number and a phone call. Read the javadoc. It explains what both classes are.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle's JAVA API Specification:

> Class URL represents a Uniform Resource Locator, a pointer to a "resource" on the World Wide Web. A resource can be something as simple as a file or a directory, or it can be a reference to a more complicated object, such as a query to a database or to a search engine.
>
> The abstract class URLConnection is the superclass of all classes that represent a communications link between the application and a URL. Instances of this class can be used both to read from and to write to the resource referenced by the URL.

A URL object simply creates an absolute URL, which is used by URLConnection objects created using openConnection() to interact with the URL over a network.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ URL represents an Uniform Resource Locator, which is merely an address. URLConnection represents a communications link between the application and a URL.

Answer (score 0):

from [Oracle web site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) : "..reading from a URLConnection instead of reading directly from a URL might be more useful. This is because you can use the URLConnection object for other tasks (like writing to the URL) at the same time."

Answer (score 0):

A URL represents the location of a resource, and a URLConnection represents a link for accessing or communicating with the resource at the location.